# Exoplayer - How to only show control buttons when clicking screen

Tags: android, exoplayer

[image]

How do I hide these media player controls when exoplayer has started. I only want to show them if the user clicks on the screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
playerView.setControllerAutoShow(false);
```

setControllerAutoShow doesn't display the media control buttons onstart

Comment: Could you describe a bit what this code is doing and how does it answer the question?